# representing decimals with commas instead of dots

Tags: graphics, number-representation

I want the decimal numbers in the axes of my graphs to be represented with commas instead of dots

Is it possible? Does anyone know how to do it?

I've made a few research, but I've got no answer.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Look up `NumberPoint`.

Comment: There's a GUI setting under Preferences -> Appearance -> Numbers -> Formatting.  I do not know how to achieve this effect programmatically, and localized to only one plot (without generating my own tick marks).  Also look up `NumberPoint`.

Comment: so simple...  thank you!